# How do I check if a thing is in a vector

Tags: rust

How do I check if a thing is in a vector?

```rust
let n= vec!["-i","mmmm"];
if "-i" in n { 
    println!("yes");
} else {
    println!("no");
```

I'm guessing that I need to put this in a loop and then do `if "-i" in x` where `x` is the iter var. But I was hopping there is a handy method available or I've confused the syntax and there is a similar way to do this.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

While you could construct a loop, an easier way would be to use the [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) method on an iterator for your vector.

`any` takes a closure that returns true or false. The closure is called for each of the items in turn until it finds one that returns true. Note that the iterator returns references to the values (thus the `&` in `|&i|`).

```
let n= vec!["-i","mmmm"];

if n.iter().any(|&i| i=="-i") {
    println!("Yes");
}
```

Since `any` operates on iterators, it can be used with any type of container. There are a large number of similar methods available on iterators, such as `all`, `find`, etc. See the standard library documentation for [`Iterators`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

Comment: Just a guess: This method would have a complexity of `O(n)`. I can't see any way to improve it. Where as `contains` could be implemented in `O(log n)`, for some data structures.

Answer (score 146):

There is the `contains` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.contains) method on `Vec`.

Example:

```
let n = vec!["-i","mmmm"];

if n.contains(&"-i") { 
    println!("yes");
} else {
    println!("no");
}
```

It is somewhat [restrictive](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42671), for instance it doesn't allow checking if a `Vec<String>` contains `x` if `x` is of type `&str`. In that case, you will have to use the `.iter().any(...)` method described by @harmic