# Is there a method like "Array.prototype.some" in rust Vector?

Tags: vector, rust

Is there a method like "Array.prototype.some" in rust Vector(or Iterator)?

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].some(v => v > 3)
```

```rust
// ?
vec![1,2,3,4,5].some(|&v| v > 3)
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any

Comment: Yes, [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a thing is in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368801/how-do-i-check-if-a-thing-is-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any).

```
vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter().any(|v| v > 3) // true
```

Incidentally, if you want the first matching element itself, not just a true or false, you can use [`Iterator::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find).

```
vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter().find(|v| v > 3) // Some(4)
```